# PHP Curl - Send a ping (without waiting for the url to load fully)

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use curl to just give ping to a script.

Unfortunately, since this will run in a hosting where exec is disabled, I cant use exec to do the ping.

I was planning to use curl with a low time out. But thats Connection timeout, and since the connection is successful, it will wait till the page load is completed.

Code :

```
$ch=curl_init();
$timeout=1;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

What I want to achieve is to ping to a page (its on my own domain, just another php script, if that helps) and not wait for the page load to complete.

Any advice guys?

Comment: Fork a child process to handle the ping.

Comment: Can you elaborate just a bit? Or mention the function to use other than `exec`